# Very simple question about functions in PHP

Tags: php

To be able to use a variable within a function that was previously defined outside of the function we do this:

```
function animal() {    
     global $favAnimal, $personName;    
     //more code here    
}
```

But how can we use a variable that is defined within a function outside that function? For example the following doesn't work:

```
function animal() {    
    $animalName = 'tiger';    
}

animal();

echo $animalName; //prints nothing
```

Comment: Is returning an object from the function or declaring an empty variable with the same name globally an option?

Comment: excuse me, why do you want to do that? It isn't reasonable. How about there's 2 variable with the same name($animalName), in  2 distinct functions? Which one would you print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access another function's *local* variables unless that function is higher up the call stack and has passed the variable into the called function. However, any function can add additional variables to the global scope.

It seems like you might be looking for the `return` statement:

```
function animal() {    
    $animalName = 'tiger';    

    return $animalName;
}

$name = animal();

echo $name; // prints 'tiger'
```

Answer (score 2):

Same way. But don't do it.

```
function animal() {    
    global $animalName;
    $animalName = 'tiger';    
}
```

Comment: What Ignacio is saying is that scopes are there for a reason, if you start including too many variables in the global scope you end up with spaghetti code

Answer (score 0):

```
function animal() {
    return 'ounce';
}

echo animal();
```

You should `return` the animal name.

And if you want to pass something into the function, use an argument, not a `global`:

```
function animal($type) {
    if ($type == 'cat') {
        return 'tiger';
    } else {
        return 'something else';
    }
}

echo animal('cat');
```

Comment: looks fine to me some one voted down 3 of us with identical answers with out explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
function animal() {    
    $animalName = 'tiger';    
return $animalName;
}

$animalName=animal();

echo $animalName; //prints tiger
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  function animal() {    
     animalName = 'tiger';  
     return $animalName;  
  }

  echo animal();
```